# Will latex paint dry thoroughly if applied too thickly

Tags: paint

I became impatient and applied latex paint to a cabinet door way too thickly.  I dumped about four ounces on the door with the door laying flat and then just spread it around with a brush.  Will the latex dry thoroughly but just take longer or did I mess this up?

Comment: everything dries eventually

Comment: That's good to hear, @jsotola.  Thank you.

Comment: I was worried that it might form a skin and not dry underneath.

Comment: You may be dissatisfied with the performance of the paint, however.  It's fairly easy to recover from latex paint mistakes if you do it early; water is a solvent, so  you can basically use water as paint remover and get it offa there.   Once gone, redo properly with proper technique.

Comment: Impatient  and DIY is not a good combination.  Stay away from power tools  and electricity.

Comment: I looked at it just now and it appears to be drying nicely.  We have over 100 degrees Fahrenheit here, right now.  If it doesn't turn out well, I will strip it off and do it over.  Maybe I spread it thin enough after all.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it will dry and it will "dry" in a couple days with right temp and air flow controls.

However with the amount that you put on there it could be a long time before the paint actually cures and it may never cure to the point of a good paint job.   Depending on a lot of variables even after it cures the inner paint may become rubbery or even worse it could become chalky and never bind right.

Comment: I'll watch to see if it gets rubbery.  I hope I don't have to do it over.  That would be a lesson to me, if I do.

Answer (score 0):

It will make it easy to strip off and redo correctly. It should peel off like plastic when it's dry. My home had very heavy latex paint on cabinets, and I was able to peel it all off with minimal scraping.

Cabinet doors should really be painted with spray enamel. It will look 10 times better and last 10 times longer than latex.

Comment: Latex paint peels off glass really well, once it has dried.  I spraypainted my bedroom walls and didn't mask anything.  When it dried, I lightly scored around the glass with a utility knife and then peeled it off the windows with a razor blade scraper.  It came off really well and left the windows really clean.